# YouTube autoplay does not work anymore

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Today I found that my youtube videos embeded in iframe does not `autoplay`

for example. 
http://www.youtube.com/embed/U3NVhtUhMbM?autoplay=1
is the `autplay` deprecated?

plus previously when pressing share button on youtube, it had `autoplay` parameter, now it's gone

Comment: Consult YouTube help, not stackoverflow.

Comment: you find the youtube forum here (tag bug): https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/youtube/bug|sort:relevance|spell:true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with YouTube API.
Star this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5595) to get updates on it.